# Why is ensureLogin not working when I am using passport-auth0-openidconnect?

Tags: javascript, jwt, openid-connect, auth0

I have a [simple express webapp](https://gist.github.com/purejgleason/40436d3e97a905a01d950c883866ce59) and I am trying to add auth. Everything seems to work fine, I see the connect.sid in the cookies etc, but when I tried to access the following endpoint...

```
this.app.get("/user",
  ensureLoggedIn("/login"),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user || {});
});
```

It redirects me to login instead of letting me through. What am I missing?

When I debug I can see that the problem is `req.isAuthenticated` is false. I am not sure why because I login and see the cookie. I can also logout and be presented with the Login screen so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had been calling `passport.session()` before I setup express session. This fixed it....

[image]